# Some of the p-values are NaN - logistic regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to do logisitc regression, but have this issue - some of the p values are NaN

```
model = sm.Logit(y2,X2.astype(float))
result = model.fit()
result.summary()
```

[image]
[image]

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: I've never used this package but my guess would be that there's a problem with these 4 variables about the time of day in the data. The main problem is not that the p-values are NaN, this is probably just a consequence of the first error "maximum likelihood failed to converge". Check the format of your data, in particular the type of these variables: they should be numerical I assume. It looks as if it doesn't find any value for these variables.

Comment: I think, this might be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55556806/8675216

Comment: They are numerical, but it can be that there are many 0's, so the article that @AkashDubey recommend could be good, I will try some other methods for logit.